# How to handle recyclerview click event on fragment?

Tags: java, android

I, know this question is already asked on community but still I am not able to resolve my issue. That's why posting this again. How to pass data from recyclerview adapter to fragment. I have successfully pass data from adapter to the activity. But not able to get how to pass data from adapter to the fragment. I have two Parameters in my database (1) mSliderImage and (2) mTitle. The mSliderImage is shown on home fragment. but now I want when user click on particular image of slider a new fragment get opens and there mTitle will be shown. I successfully able to open new fragment on click of image-slider base on image position. But not getting how to pass mTitle in that fragment. Please someone help me the whole code because I have to submit this college level project by 17th of January. I am only posting the important code not my whole code. I just want coding solution of how to pass mSliderTitle from adapter to the fragment. when I click on some image of Image Slider.

Below is my code:

In Model I have passed 2 Getters ans Setters already mentioned above. (1) mSliderImage and (2) mTitle.

Slider Adapter:

```
public class SliderImageAdapter extends SliderViewAdapter<SliderImageAdapter.SliderAdapterVH>{

    public List<Banner> bannerList;
    public Context context;
    private OnItemClicked onClick;

    public interface OnItemClicked {
        void onItemClick(int position);
    }

    public SliderImageAdapter(Context context, List<Banner> bannerList, OnItemClicked onClick) {

        this.bannerList = bannerList;
        this.context = context;
        this.onClick = onClick;
    }

    @Override
    public SliderAdapterVH onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent) {
        View inflate = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.image_slider_myshop, parent, false);
        return new SliderAdapterVH(inflate);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final SliderAdapterVH viewHolder, final int position) {

Glide.with(viewHolder.itemView)
                .load(bannerList.get(position).getmSliderImage())
                .into(viewHolder.imageViewBackground);


        viewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                onClick.onItemClick(position);
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return bannerList.size();
    }

    public int getItemPosition (Object object) {
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    public void setOnClick(OnItemClicked onClick) {
        this.onClick = onClick;
    }



    class SliderAdapterVH extends SliderViewAdapter.ViewHolder {
View itemView;
    ImageView imageViewBackground;

    public SliderAdapterVH(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);
        imageViewBackground = itemView.findViewById(R.id.iv_auto_image_slider);
        this.itemView = itemView;

        }
    }
```

Home Fragment: (Here Image Slider is Shown. and I want when user click a new fragment get open and show mTitle).

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements SliderImageAdapter.OnItemClicked {

private SliderImageAdapter sliderImageAdapter;
    private List<Banner> bannerList;

bannerList = new ArrayList<>();
        sliderImageAdapter = new SliderImageAdapter(getActivity(), bannerList, this);

@Override
    public void onItemClick(int position) {

        FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();
        ft.add(R.id.fragment_container_dashboard, SliderClickFragment.newInstance());
        ft.addToBackStack(null);
        ft.commit();
    }
```

Slider Click Fragment XML:

```
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

<TextView
 android:id="@+id/mSliderTitle"
 android:layout_width="match_parent"
 android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Slider Click Fragment Java: (Here I want to show mTitle when user click on image)

```
public class SliderClickFragment extends Fragment {

    public static SliderClickFragment newInstance() {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        SliderClickFragment fragment = new SliderClickFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.slider_click_listner,container,false);

        return view;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this. I haven't tested but this flow should get what you are trying to achieve.

HomeFragment.java

```
public class HomeFragment extends Fragment implements SliderImageAdapter.OnItemClicked {

private SliderImageAdapter sliderImageAdapter;
    private List<Banner> bannerList;

bannerList = new ArrayList<>();
        sliderImageAdapter = new SliderImageAdapter(getActivity(), bannerList, this);

@Override
    public void onItemClick(int position) {

    //GET THE TITLE STRING HERE
    String title = bannerList.get(position).getmSliderTitle();

    FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
    FragmentTransaction ft = fm.beginTransaction();

    //PASS THIS TITLE TO THE FRAGMENT INSTANCE LIKE THIS
    ft.add(R.id.fragment_container_dashboard, SliderClickFragment.newInstance(title));

    ft.addToBackStack(null);
    ft.commit();
}
```

SliderClickFragment.java

```
public class SliderClickFragment extends Fragment {

//EDIT the newInstance Method definition to include title like this:
public static SliderClickFragment newInstance(String title) {
    Bundle args = new Bundle();

    //PASS THE STRING IN THE BUNDLE WHICH WILL THEN BE FETCHED IN ONCREATEVIEW LATER LIKE THIS
    args.putString("title", title);

    SliderClickFragment fragment = new SliderClickFragment();
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.slider_click_listner,container,false);

    //GET THE STRING HERE AND THEN USE IT HOWEVER YOU LIKE
    String title = getArguments().getString("title");

    return view;
}
```

}

Comment: Thanks, Task Done Successfully. Can you help me one more thing. after I clicking on image mTitle is shown in new fragment. but  If I am on that fragment and update values in my firestore it doesn't reflect on real time basis. means I have to go back to home fragment then again have to come to slider click fragment to see those changes.

Comment: Can you mark it as accepted answer if it helped? Also, regarding your second question, are you updating the value via App or directly accessing the Firestore DB outside App. If it is via App, then after you update, you can just send a 'broadcast' which will trigger auto update of UI. Lookup 'broadcast receiver'. But if you are doing from outside App, I doubt you can capture that from App.